# Capturing text from href

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, href

```
<h1 class="currentStatusUserName">
<a href="/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage">Apttus 0614CommSalesRep1</a>
```

I'm trying to capture into a variable `Apttus 0614CommSalesRep1` but I'm  not successful with the following

```
salesUser = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        "//a[@href='/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage']"))
    .getText();
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your xpath is pointing to the correct element by doing another test that doesn't involve getting the text?

Comment: Additionally, is the <a> tag a child of the <h1> tag?

Comment: I ran this as above with the .getText and I received no error that implied the xpath was incorrect.  When I tried to print out salesUser it was blank so my assumption was the xpath was ok but just didn't like the .getText. The a tag is a child.

Comment: If the a is either the first child, or the only child, you could try a simplification of your xpath assuming currentStatusUserName is a unique class on the page. `//h1[@class='currentStatusUserName']/a`

Answer (score 1):

Alternate methods for `.getText()`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getAttribute("textContent");
```

Comment: The innerHTML grabbed a lot of data. I was hopping only only 'Apttus 0614CommSalesRep1' would be returned. I guess I can try and parse it out. The textContent  didn't anything. thanks

Comment: @user1732506, what other data did it grab? If your xpath is correct, it should only get what is inside the `<a>` tags. And if all else fails, you can use various string manipulation functions to trim away any text you don't want/need.